# Logging Strategy for AWS Spot Instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, logging, log-files

I have a use case where I need to send Logs from a AWS EC2 spot instance to AWS Cloud Watch.

Can any body suggest me a process where I can collect the logs from the Spot instance and send it to cloud watch. I know the process of sending the logs to AWS Cloud Watch but many times what happens is Spot instance gets terminated in like 5 Min due to price change so want to make sure the logs gets captured before the instance is terminated.

Comment: If your logs are taking longer than a second or two to be shipped off of the box they're generated on, you have other problems to resolve.

Comment: Do you mean large logs like huge web server access logs, or small pieces of information? Is this for CW Logs to monitor logs for alerts, or is it purely for storage of logs? You might not be using the right service.